# Certain fonts not applying to specific views

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, fonts

Minimal Reproducible Example (Using only built-in fonts):

```
@main
struct FontExampleApp: App {
    @StateObject private var appearanceManager = AppearanceManager()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(appearanceManager)

        }
    }
}

class AppearanceManager: ObservableObject {

    @Published var Font: String = "System" {
        didSet {
            saveFont()
            objectWillChange.send()
            print("Set font to \(Font)")
            print("Corresponding font name: \(fonts[Font])")
        }
    }
    
    public let fonts = ["System" : "system-default", // unrecognized name defaults to system font
                        "Times New Roman" : "TimesNewRomanPSMT",
                        "Trebuchet" : "TrebuchetMS"
    ]
    
    init() {
        loadFont()
        
        for family in UIFont.familyNames.sorted() {
            let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
            print("Family: \(family) Font names: \(names)")
        }
    }
    
    private let fontKey = "FontKey"
    
    private func saveFont() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(Font, forKey: fontKey)
    }
    
    private func loadFont() {
        if let savedFont = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: fontKey) as? String {
            Font = savedFont
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PostView()
            Spacer()
            FontSelectionView()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


struct PostView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appearanceManager: AppearanceManager
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
                Text("Hello World")
                // below only works for certain fonts
                    .font(.custom(appearanceManager.Font, size: 30, relativeTo: .title))
                
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct FontSelectionView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appearanceManager: AppearanceManager

    var body: some View {
        Section(header: Text("Fonts")) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(appearanceManager.fonts.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { fontName in
                    FontButton(name: fontName)
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 5)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FontButton: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appearanceManager: AppearanceManager

    let name: String
    var isSelected: Bool {
        appearanceManager.Font == name
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(name)
                .font(.custom(appearanceManager.fonts[name] ?? "", size: 17, relativeTo: .body))
            Spacer()
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .foregroundColor(isSelected ? .secondary : .clear)
                .overlay(
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(Color.primary, lineWidth: 2)
                )
        }
        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                appearanceManager.Font = name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The example above only uses two custom fonts, both of which are built-in. Notice that Times New Roman works as expected, but Trebuchet does not.

This minimal reproducible example extends to the situation described below, which involves both built-in and third-party fonts.

I've added custom fonts to my project and have successfully been able to use each font to stylize text but only in a settings menu:

```
class AppearanceManager: ObservableObject {

    @Published var Font: String = "System" {
        didSet {
            saveFont()
            objectWillChange.send()
            print("Set font to \(Font)")
            print("Corresponding font name: \(fonts[Font])")
        }
    }
    
    public let fonts = ["System" : "system-default", // unrecognized name defaults to system font
                        "Courier Prime" : "CourierPrime-Regular",
                        "JetBrains Mono" : "JetBrainsMono-Regular",
                        "Roboto" : "RobotoMono-Regular",
                        "Ubuntu" : "UbuntuMono-Regular",
                        "Victor" : "VictorMono-Regular",
                        "Times New Roman" : "TimesNewRomanPSMT",
                        "Trebuchet" : "TrebuchetMS"
    ]
    
    init() {
        loadFont()
        
        // used for debugging
        for family in UIFont.familyNames.sorted() {
            let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
            print("Family: \(family) Font names: \(names)")
        }
    }
    
    private let fontKey = "FontKey"
    
    private func saveFont() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(Font, forKey: fontKey)
    }
    
    private func loadFont() {
        if let savedFont = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: fontKey) as? String {
            Font = savedFont
        }
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appearanceManager: AppearanceManager
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            FontSelectionView()
        }
        .navigationTitle("Settings")
    }
}

struct FontSelectionView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appearanceManager: AppearanceManager

    var body: some View {
        Section(header: Text("Fonts")) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(appearanceManager.fonts.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { fontName in
                    FontButton(name: fontName)
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 5)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FontButton: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appearanceManager: AppearanceManager

    let name: String
    var isSelected: Bool {
        appearanceManager.Font == name
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(name)
                .font(.custom(appearanceManager.fonts[name] ?? "", size: 17, relativeTo: .body))
            Spacer()
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .foregroundColor(isSelected ? .secondary : .clear)
                .overlay(
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(Color.primary, lineWidth: 2)
                )
        }
        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                appearanceManager.Font = name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above can be used to apply each font to text:
[image]

However certain fonts (not just custom fonts I added to my project, but also built-in fonts such as Trebuchet) are not being applied to text elements throughout my app:

```
struct PostView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appearanceManager: AppearanceManager
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
                
                Text("Hello World")
                    // below only works for certain fonts
                    .font(.custom(appearanceManager.Font, size: 30, relativeTo: .title))

            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

I have injected the EnvironmentObject to the root view of my app

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    @StateObject private var appearanceManager = AppearanceManager()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(appearanceManager)
        }
    }
}
```

I have also printed all available fonts and determined that the actual font name is being published:

```
// prints in init() method: 
...
Family: Times New Roman Font names: ["TimesNewRomanPSMT", "TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT", "TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT", "TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT"]
Family: Trebuchet MS Font names: ["TrebuchetMS", "TrebuchetMS-Italic", "TrebuchetMS-Bold", "Trebuchet-BoldItalic"]
Family: Ubuntu Mono Font names: ["UbuntuMono-Regular"]
Family: Verdana Font names: ["Verdana", "Verdana-Italic", "Verdana-Bold", "Verdana-BoldItalic"]
Family: Victor Mono Font names: ["VictorMono-Regular"]
...

// prints when I set a font: 

Set font to Trebuchet
Corresponding font name: Optional("TrebuchetMS") // Not applied outside of settings menu


Set font to JetBrains Mono
Corresponding font name: Optional("JetBrainsMono-Regular") // works as expected

Set font to Roboto
Corresponding font name: Optional("RobotoMono-Regular") // not applied outside of settings menu
```

Comment: Please consider turning this question into a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Stoic I have prepended my initial post with an MRE I didn't remove content from my initial post because it describes the nuance that all fonts are able to be applied to text within my `FontButton` view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seemingly have confused yourself with what `AppearanceManager.Font` should be storing. If it stores the *actual font name* (the one that `.custom` would recognise), then the tap gesture in `FontButton` is not correct:

```
.onTapGesture {
    withAnimation {
        appearanceManager.Font = name
    }
}
```

`name` here is the *display name* of the font that the button displays in its `Text`.

If `AppearanceManager.Font` is supposed to store the display name, then this in `PostView` is not correct:

```
.font(.custom(appearanceManager.Font, size: 30, relativeTo: .title))
```

You should not pass a display name to `.custom`.

`"Times New Roman"` here just so happens to "work", because it is the family name of the font, and `.custom` can recognise that. The family name for TrebuchetMS would be "Trebuchet MS" (with an extra space). Also consider using the family names as options instead. Most, if not all, family names are suitable for display.

Anyway, you should decide what `AppearanceManager.Font` should be storing, and make your code consistent with that.

I would recommend storing the actual font name, and also introducing a struct that represents a display name-font name pair.

```
struct FontOption: Identifiable, Hashable{
    let fontName: String
    let displayName: String
    
    var id: String { fontName }
}
```

Unless you want to not immediately save the font to user defaults for some reason, I would recommend using `@AppStorage`. The `AppearanceManager` would look like:

```
class AppearanceManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @AppStorage("FontKey") var font: String = ""
    
    public let fonts = [
        FontOption(fontName: "", displayName: "System"),
        FontOption(fontName: "TimesNewRomanPSMT", displayName: "Times New Roman"),
        FontOption(fontName: "TrebuchetMS", displayName: "Trebuchet"),
    ]
}
```

And at this point, if `AppearanceManager` doesn't have any other members, I would remove `AppearanceManager` and use `@AppStorage` in views directly. `fonts` can just be a global constant.

The rest of the code looks like this:

```
struct PostView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appearanceManager: AppearanceManager
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
                Text("Hello World")
                    .font(.custom(appearanceManager.font, size: 30, relativeTo: .title))
                
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct FontSelectionView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appearanceManager: AppearanceManager
    
    var body: some View {
        Section(header: Text("Fonts")) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(appearanceManager.fonts) { font in
                    FontButton(font: font)
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 5)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FontButton: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appearanceManager: AppearanceManager
    
    let font: FontOption
    
    var isSelected: Bool {
        appearanceManager.font == font.fontName
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(font.displayName)
                .font(.custom(font.fontName, size: 17, relativeTo: .body))
            Spacer()
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .foregroundColor(isSelected ? .secondary : .clear)
                .overlay(
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(Color.primary, lineWidth: 2)
                )
        }
        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                appearanceManager.font = font.fontName
            }
        }
    }
}
```